# Layout not supporting in all screens

Tags: android

I am new to android , i am developing registration screen 
I have used scroll view to support in smaller screens, but when it comes to larger screens 7 inches layout is not fitting .

I don't know how to make this layout fit in all screens such that in small screens it should be scrollable 
I have searched in internet but it is of no use, so please help me on how to make my screen adaptable to all screens of android.`
Here is the code i am using:

`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="338dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <EditText
        android:hint="@string/phoneno"
        android:id="@+id/usr_reg_et_phoneno"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/style_edittext"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/usr_reg_et_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:background="@drawable/style_edittext"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" >

    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/usr_reg_et_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:background="@drawable/style_edittext"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/usr_reg_et_pwd"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:background="@drawable/style_edittext"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.22" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggle_gender"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/gender_check"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false" 
            android:checked="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/toggle_gender"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/toggle_gender"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
            android:text="@string/gender"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#818080" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/toggle_user"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/toggle_gender"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toggle_gender"
            android:background="@drawable/user_check"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/login_et_phoneno"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/toggle_user"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/toggle_user"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
            android:text="@string/role"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#818080" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/tc"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="@drawable/radar"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progressbar3" 
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/usr_reg_bt_register"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/style_button"
    android:text="@string/register" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/usr_reg_tv_tc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/usr_reg_bt_register"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
    android:text="@string/tclink"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#336600" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

`

Comment: You may wish to post a screenshot somewhere and link to it from your post, to illustrate what "not fitting" means.

Comment: lot of detail [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 1):

Please refer these link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

For Different screen size, The following is a list of resource directories in an application that provides different layout designs for different screen sizes and different bitmap drawables for small, medium, high, and extra high density screens.You still need to edit the layout resource to fit better

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
  res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
  res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
  res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
  res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

  res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
  res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
  res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

The following code in the Manifest supports all dpis.

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
      android:normalScreens="true" 
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:xlargeScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Comment: Please explain how your answer points out the specific problems in the layout posted in the question.

Comment: user3728438 have to make all these layout in res folder and also have to take all size of images in diff diff drawable folder for multiple screens

Comment: Simply having layout files in separate directories does not magically cause them to fit better. You still need to edit the layout resource to fit better. That is what the question is asking, and your answer does not explain how to edit the layout resource to fit better.

Comment: commonsware its  still need to edit the layout resource to fit better then only we have to make diff diff layout dude which easily user can see in graphical layout of xml dude

Comment: i added ur line in my ans :)